# Missing close parenthesis on subquery PHRETS

Tags: php, rets, phrets

I am getting

> Missing close parenthesis on subquery

error while trying to get listings using RETS 
https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS/issues/104

Here is the code query I am passing

```
$results = $rets->Search('Property', '1', "(138=2016-01-01+),(37=|601,602,603,604,605,606),(242=|ER,S,X),(68=3+),(122=3+)",
        [
        'QueryType' => 'DMQL',
        'Count' => 1, 
        'Format' => 'COMPACT',
        'Limit' => 99999999,
        ]);
```

Comment: @IsraGab - Thank you for edit suggestio

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests to me that one of those fields is a field type that doesn't exactly match the type of value you're searching.

Can you use something like www.retsmd.com to see what the defined types are for those fields in the query?

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried using that as well but same error.
Query is copied from Developer guide PDF provided by API provider.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, posting the answer if helpful for anyone.
field didn't exist so it was throwing error, which wasn't relevant to actual error.